# ext sheaf and cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ with $\mbox{dim}(\mathcal{F}) = 0$. It's true that cohomology $H^{i}(\mathbb{P}^{3}, ext^{3}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}})) = 0$ for $i = 1,\, 2,\,3$? If so, what result guarantees this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $F$ has dimension zero, the same holds for $\mathcal{E}xt^3(F,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3})$ and then the vanishing is clear.

Comment: Ok, Mohan. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Lemma~II.1.1.2 in [Okonek, Christian; Schneider, Michael; Spindler, Heinz. Vector bundles on complex projective spaces].

Comment: So, this lemma tells us that: If $i > \mbox{dim}(\mathcal{F})$, then $H^{i} = 0$, correct?

Comment: This Lemma tells that if $i + k > n$ then $H^i(\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^k(F,G)) = 0$. The dimension of the support of $F$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I apologize, but I really did not understand why this lemma says that: if $i + k > n$, then $H^{i}(\mbox{ext}^{k}(F, G)) = 0$?

Comment: Lemma: For a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over $n$-dimensional complex manifold $X$ we have: $\mbox{dim}(supp(\mbox{ext}^{i}(\mathcal{F}, O_{X}))) \leq n - i $ for all i. (Lemma~II.1.1.2 [Okonek, Christian]).

Comment: If $G$ is a coherent sheaf then $H^i(G) = 0$ for $i > \dim supp(G)$.

Comment: ok. Now it's clearer for me. Thank you very much, Sasha.